# Transformers Decoder Inputs (Keys and Values)

Tags: attention, encoder-decoder

I am trying to better understand the encoder-decoder transformer architecture.
I understand the high-level intuition behind the concept of keys, queries and values. For example, in the context of CV, the Queries and Keys are creating various 'attention filters and values are the original image information. So for example, there could be various attention filters focusing on various aspects of the images. Once this is all computed and the final output is obtained from the encoder block, these are passed as Key, and Values. I am not sure whether these are the same tensors being duplicated and passed on as keys, and values? And the decoder provides queries. Why would we need to pass two identical matrices?

Secondly, I am not sure I fully understand the purpose of positional embedding with sin/cosine functions? What/why is it used rather than the simple index in an image?

Pardon my knowledge of incorrect understanding above. I am trying to better understand this beast.

Thank you for your patience.